# Retrieving Project URLs and Project Download URLs of Fedora Packages

Tags: fedora, opensource-projects

I have a list of all fedora packages in a .txt file and would like to retrieve the Project URLs and Project Download URLs of all these packages.

The command `dnf info <package>` does yield a download URL which could be used to download the latest version of the package. An example is as follows:

```
Last metadata expiration check: 1:33:08 ago on Tue Aug  9 12:58:18 2022.
Installed Packages
Name         : alternatives
Version      : 1.19
Release      : 2.fc36
Architecture : x86_64
Size         : 62 k
Source       : chkconfig-1.19-2.fc36.src.rpm
Repository   : @System
From repo    : anaconda
Summary      : A tool to maintain symbolic links determining default commands
URL          : https://github.com/fedora-sysv/chkconfig
License      : GPLv2
Description  : alternatives creates, removes, maintains and displays information about the
             : symbolic links comprising the alternatives system. It is possible for several
             : programs fulfilling the same or similar functions to be installed on a single
             : system at the same time.
```

However, I would like to get the URL of the actual ongoing project itself. Is there any easy way to do so? Help deeply appreciated!

**Another Example:**

```
Name         : audit-libs
Version      : 3.0.8
Release      : 1.fc36
Architecture : x86_64
Size         : 299 k
Source       : audit-3.0.8-1.fc36.src.rpm
Repository   : @System
From repo    : anaconda
Summary      : Dynamic library for libaudit
URL          : http://people.redhat.com/sgrubb/audit/
License      : LGPLv2+
Description  : The audit-libs package contains the dynamic libraries needed for
             : applications to use the audit framework.
```

Answer (score 1):

The URL given in the `URL` field *is* the URL of the “ongoing project”: https://github.com/fedora-sysv/chkconfig is where `chkconfig` is hosted, and http://people.redhat.com/sgrubb/audit/ is where Audit is hosted; even though the URLs suggest they are respectively Fedora-specific and Red Hat-specific, these really are the projects’ pages. You can compare the URLs with those references in other projects; for example, [the Debian Audit package](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/audit) also points to http://people.redhat.com/sgrubb/audit/ (look for the “Homepage” link).

Other packages may make that more obvious; consider

```
$ dnf info libevdev
Available Packages
Name         : libevdev
Version      : 1.10.0
Release      : 1.el8
Architecture : i686
Size         : 43 k
Source       : libevdev-1.10.0-1.el8.src.rpm
Repository   : rhel-8-for-x86_64-appstream-rpms
Summary      : Kernel Evdev Device Wrapper Library
URL          : http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/libevdev
License      : MIT
Description  : libevdev is a library to wrap kernel evdev devices and provide a proper API
             : to interact with those devices.
```

which points to [the `libevdev` page on FDO](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/libevdev), or

```
$ dnf info gcc
Installed Packages
Name         : gcc
Version      : 8.5.0
Release      : 10.1.el8_6
Architecture : x86_64
Size         : 59 M
Source       : gcc-8.5.0-10.1.el8_6.src.rpm
Repository   : @System
From repo    : rhel-8-for-x86_64-appstream-rpms
Summary      : Various compilers (C, C++, Objective-C, ...)
URL          : http://gcc.gnu.org
License      : GPLv3+ and GPLv3+ with exceptions and GPLv2+ with exceptions and LGPLv2+ and BSD
Description  : The gcc package contains the GNU Compiler Collection version 8.
             : You'll need this package in order to compile C code.
```

which points to [the GCC project page](http://gcc.gnu.org).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! My bad for quoting that example. But, in the example you quoted, the URL seems like a version download URL and not really the project URL?

Comment: This really is the project URL. I’ve added another example which is hopefully clear enough.

Comment: Thank you very much! So, the URL field is indeed returning the project URLs itself!